# How to give an angular 8 component body a background-color?

Tags: html, css, angular

How can I change the body background-color for this component? I am using angular 8.

```
<div class="container-fluid home-container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
  <div class="home-login-shape-container">
    <div class="home-login-shape-bg mx-auto">
      <div class="home-login-container d-flex flex-column justify-content- 
           center align-items-center">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

```
html, body {
min-height: 100%;
background: green;
}


.home-container {
color: var(--col-pale);
 min-height: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: "roboto-reg";
 overflow-y: hidden;
 background-color: red;
}

.home-login-shape-bg {
 background-image: 
 url("../../assets/images/ui/shape_login_dt_1024x682.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 background-position: center;
 height: 682px;
```

}

I cant seem to get the background color to change. I can change it for the root element but I specifically want to change the color for a single component

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: try declaring your css in the component.scss file. It looks like you are declaring in the styles.scss where u define global styles. Usually angular provides view encapsulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fixed it for me

```
:host {
 display: block;
 background-color: green;
}


.home-container {
color: var(--col-pale);
height: 100vh;
font-family: "roboto-reg";
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

@saget Thank you for your help!

Comment: You don't need any top level container in Angular components due to `:host`. Also you may want to have a look at `host-context` (useful for conditional styles depending on parent the component is wrapped with)

Comment: @Sergey using a top level container(height : 100vh) was necessary for me. Without setting it the background-color took only 40% of the template.

Answer (score 0):

There is CSS property in angular called as **host**. So in your component's CSS/Scss file, you can do below:-

```
:host {
      display: block;
      background-color: red;
}
```

So below code is only applicable to the component which is your host element.

Comment: :host is targeting the home-container

Comment: :host will target your actual component. For example, <app-demo></app-demo>. But I believe  "background-color" on "home-container" class override your host styles. Can you try with removing style on that?

Answer (score 0):

move whole component content into main div and you can change style as you need

```
<div class="main-div">
<div class="container-fluid home-container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
  <div class="home-login-shape-container">
    <div class="home-login-shape-bg mx-auto">
      <div class="home-login-container d-flex flex-column justify-content- 
       center align-items-center">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.main-div { background-color: #09c;}
```